# What google services do I need to install on android device to get google maps working?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm working on a city device (That large interactive display) that is running android 5.1.

The app is working just fine on emulator, however the City Display did not come with google play services, and the google maps is not working on it.

Which google services and which versions of it do I need to install to get the maps to work?
Where can I download it? (There is no google play store on that device)

this is set it build.gradle

```
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.2.1'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
```

https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps

I tried to download some of them from apkmirror but with no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded an app information app from apkmirror so I could correctly find which version of google play services I needed and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I believe [standalone v3 beta](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/v3-client-migration) works without Google Play Services.

> v.3.0.0 BETA - May 07, 2019
> The Maps SDK for Android is now distributed via a standalone static
> library. Previously, the Maps SDK for Android was made available as
> part of Google Play services.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I found a specific version of google play services for that device before I tried your solution and it worked!

Comment: My opinion: If device comes without Google Play Services, I think it's safer to find a solution without them (stock device).